# Launch Image For Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Now am using Xcode 5 for creating application.My problem is related with Launch Image.
My problem is,When app launches suddenly a black screen will appear and then splash screen(Aditional viewcontroller for splash screen) loading smoothly.
I already set default.png(320*480) as launch image.In Xcode 4.5 it  was working perfect.I don't why the a black screen is appear when app launch instead of default.png.What i am missing?

...Advanced thanks...

This is code am using for spashviewController:

```
Appdelegate *appdelegate=(Appdelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
int ht=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
////NSLog(@"ht is %d",ht);
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 71, 320,ht-64)];
if(appdelegate.window.frame.size.height==568)
{
    // code for 4-inch screen
    ////NSLog(@"iPhone 5 Screen");
    ////NSLog(@"main view nd main image view is resizable so noo need to set frame,just change the the image of main image view");
    backgroundimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x.png"];
    activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(141,476,20,10);

} else {
    backgroundimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 1):

Having a black screen when starting up does not have anything to do with any code you write - it always means you don't have the default image defined the right way.

Try to use an **asset catalog** for your launch image(s), and set all required default images - if it's iPhone only, that would be 320x480, 640x960, and 640x1136.

You can create an asset catalog by clicking *Use Asset Catalog* in your project -> General page.